# I want to add a large icon to my notification, but when I run the app, the large icon doesn't show up. Below is my code, any help where it is wrong?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to create notification with large and small icons, but the notification displayed with only small icon, title and sub titles !

I appreciated if somebody can help me.
I write these code for create Notifications

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editTitle, editSubTitle;
private Button btn_send_simple;
private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
private NotificationManagerCompat nmc;
private Notification notification;
private Bitmap largeIcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
    editSubTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_sub_title);
    largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_sport);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "");
    builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call)
            .setContentTitle(editTitle.getText().toString())
            .setContentText(editSubTitle.getText().toString())
    ;
    nmc = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notification = builder.build();
}

public void sendSimpleNotif(View view) {
    builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call)
            .setContentTitle(editTitle.getText().toString())
            .setContentText(editSubTitle.getText().toString()) ;

    notification = builder.build();
    nmc = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    nmc.notify(500, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For large icon in notification  try this:

```
Notification notification = new     

NotificationCompat.Builder(context,                          

 CHANNEL_ID)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_post)      .setContentTitle(imageTitle)
 .setContentText(imageDescription)
 .setStyle(new                        

 NotificationCompat
 .BigPictureStyle()
  .bigPicture(myBitmap))
 .build();
```

Pass your icon as bitmap here. 
for more help try this link too
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#java

Comment: thanks @unzila but still doesn't work , i run it on API 24